# upload images on bootstrap model and load new uploaded image

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, croppic

## This model will load on click on icon image.

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="profilePicModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">           
                <div class="modal-body"><div id="jsoneditor">
                    <img src="" id="profilePic" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" >
                </div></div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

## JS code for click on icon image then open model change new image on model.

```
$("#image").on("click", function() {
       $('#profilePic').attr('src', $(this).attr('value'));
       $('#profilePicModal').modal('show');
       $('#profilePic').cropper({
        aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
        crop: function(e) {

        }
});
    });
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Actually i want make a change profile image like gmail.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code to change images based on user selection. The images are placed in the same folder as the HTML file.

```
<script>
    function go(loc) {
        document.getElementById('imagechange').src = loc;
    }
</script>

<body>
    <iframe id="imagechange" src="about:blank" width="1000" height="450" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>

    <form method="post">
        <input name="calendarSelection" type="button" Value=" River1" onclick="go('river2.jpg')" />
        <input name="calendarSelection" type="button" value=" GitHub" onclick="go('riverrafting.jpg')" />
        <input name="calendarSelection" type="button" value=" Wikipedia"  onclick="go('Employee.jpg')" />

    </form>

</body>
```